# eclipse not recognizing servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-juno

I am getting a very serious and strange problem. When I am creating a servlet in eclipse juno it is not recognizing its methods and annotations.I don't why this is happening.I am using eclipse juno with glassfish server.On my another pc same glassfish server is installed with eclipse indigo and it is working fine.please guide me about this issue
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please right click on
project -> build path -> configure build path 
click on Libraries tab
Now here either your server would not be right or jre system library.
Edit the path for wrong thing :)
Thanks